# Django login using custom backend

Tags: python, django, django-authentication, django-login

I am working on a store based authentication system using Django, i am trying to make it so that the url is the one that specifies which store the user is trying to log in. Ex

```
login/store-name
```

then login the user in to the requested store. My question is, is there a way to do this using django's built in login form/mechanism or would i have to create my own login form and view.

Comment: You'll need to write your own view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you should create your own form and [login view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#authentication-in-web-requests):

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

def my_view(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active  *** and user can login in this store ***:
            login(request, user)
            # Redirect to a success page.
        else:
            # Return a 'disabled account' error message
    else:
        # Return an 'invalid login' error message.
```

"and user can login in this store": get path from request and check it.

Comment: i guess this is the best solution :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do this just in urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^login/store-name-1/$', login, name="login"),
    url(r'^login/store-name-2/$', login, name="login"),
    url(r'^accounts/logout/$', logout, {'next_page': '/',}, name='logout')
)
```

I'm not exactly clear on what you want to do?

Comment: im using a generic url pattern that takes a  store name, and then logs the user in to that specific store

Answer (score 1):

If you want separate logins for each store, you will need to customize the login form, since the django auth package will create users that are universal to all of your stores.